# generic class based view CreateView - how to compare the request.user to a certain modelobject.user

Tags: python, django, create-view

Inside my generic CreateView class based view, I want to compare the request.user to a certain modelinstance.user, and if the users dont match, I want to raise a 404 error, how can I achieve this? Which method inside the generic.CreateView should I modify and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Ruben Adriannse- Does this work?test_func is a function "that checks that the user passes the given test"

```
class RegisterUserView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = ChatUser
    template_name = 'login/registration_page.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    second_form_class = ProfileForm
    permission_denied_message = _("You are already registered!")

    def test_func(self):
        #write your logic here and return True or False based on your logic
        return self.request.user.is_anonymous
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mixins in your views.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```